# Error saying "server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized..." when trying to make connection to MySQL 8.0.11 on Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to create a web project using Java in Eclipse and every time I try to run an html file, it spits out an error message saying the following:

**The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)**

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a JDBC bug. The same thing has been causing me issues for the past week, I backtracked from mysql-connector-java version 8.0.12 to 5.1.46. Here are some of the resources I found online, let me know how it works.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Embedded-to-External-mysql-Cloudera-Manager-is-not-starting/td-p/77219

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85816

Goodluck!